# SP2013 - Create a view that groups based on individual selections in a multi choice field

Tags: 2013, list-view, multiple-values

In SP2013 I have a wiki page library that contains a multiple choice field. I'm looking to create a view that groups items based on individual terms selected in the multiple choice field. As an example:

```
Name            subjectCategory
----            ---------------
Item1           Subj1;Subj2
Item2           Subj1
Item3           Subj3
Item4           Subj2;Subj3
Item5           Subj4
```

When the view renders, it should show this:

```
Category: Subj1 (2)
    Item1
    Item2
Category: Subj2 (2)
    Item1
    Item4
Category: Subj3 (2)
    Item3
    Item4
Category: Subj4 (1)
    Item5
```

Does any know how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

A MultiChoice field is stored in one field in the database, so you need to split that into separate values and built the View yourself using CSR (Client Side Rendering)

100% Custom Coding