# create a view that groups multi choice column values

Tags: document-library, column, view, multiple-values

I apologize in advance if I am breaking rules by asking a question similar to one already asked ([SP2013 - Create a view that groups based on individual selections in a multi choice field](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/157074/sp2013-create-a-view-that-groups-based-on-individual-selections-in-a-multi-cho)). I can't seem to add comments there, so I am asking the question here.

I want to create a View that groups documents in my library based on their document type (SOP, Policy, etc.) for ease of use. The problem is that I made this column value multi-choice so that users can select multiple document types to view at once. Would this work if I created an identical Doc Type column that wasn't multi-choice and used that to group the documents, but kept it hidden so that only the original multi-choice Doc Type column showed to users so that they can still search/filter by multiple doc types?

EDIT

My solution technically works, but it is very messy. I do not recommend it unless you are willing to do extra work. Definitely don't do it if you are not ALWAYS the person tagging the metadata.